# converter decimal e data no LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Estou importando um arquivo CVS para MySQL. Tenho duas colunas: uma `quantidade` e a outra como `data`. Estou tentando converter para o padrão do MySQL. No banco esta coluna está como `decimal` e `date`. Está importando todos os registro, só que estes dois campos estão sendo salvos com `0` na `quantidade` e `null` como data. Estou errando na conversão e não o que.

Arquivo CSV

```
nome do material;03B;BC 03;800000235213364;14,000;22/06/2017
nome do material;03B;BC 03;800000235213355;14,000;22/06/2017
nome do material;03B;BC 03;800000235213358;14,000;22/06/2017
nome do material;03B;BC 03;800000235213353;14,000;22/06/2017
```

Código

```
mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/wamp/www/transbordo-sap/estoque/Estoque.csv' 
     INTO TABLE deposito FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
     OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
     (Material,Tipo,Posicao,HU,@Qtdd,@Data)  
     SET Qtdd = REPLACE(REPLACE('@Qtdd', '.', ''), ',', '.'),
         Data = STR_TO_DATE(@Data,'%Y-%m-%d')")or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim, veja se resolve:

```
mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/wamp/www/transbordo-sap/estoque/Estoque.csv' 
     INTO TABLE deposito FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
     OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
     (Material,Tipo,Posicao,HU,@Qtdd,@Data)  
     SET Qtdd = CAST(@Qtdd as DECIMAL(9,2)),
         Data = STR_TO_DATE(@Data, '%d/%m/%Y')")or die (mysql_error());
```

Fiz o teste e inseriu normalmente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]